# How to define the VPN PPTP port in OSX Lion

Tags: macos, vpn, port

Is there any change to set the port to use when connecting to a PPTP VPN from a Mac?

I configured a VPN at home from Server 2008 so I can access my home server and use ports like RDP, VNC, IMAPS (Gmail), ..., that are blocked at my workplace.

The problem is that port 1723 is also blocked.
So I configured my home router to accept requests on port 443 (HTTPS) and forward it to port 1723 of the VPN Server.

Can I tell the OSX to use port 443 instead of 1723 for that VPN connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not going to work. PPTP uses TCP port 1723 as a **control port**. Once that's established your actual tunnel is built as a **GRE tunnel**. If port 1723 is filtered then GRE is likely filtered as well.

I would suggest using [OpenVPN](http://openvpn.net/) instead. It's quite easy to set up and you can make it use only TCP port 443.

Comment: Ok, thanks... I was expecting that answer, but worth the try... I didn't wanted to use VPN because lack of iPhone support... But it is better than nothing! Thanks!